# Windows 7 domain configuration set default username

Tags: windows-7, login, active-directory

I manage a small domain network with Windows Server 2012 R2 as an Active Directory server and Windows 7 Pro on client computers. Regularly I have to login to the clients computer with my domain credentials: DNAME\Admin. I always do it after work, so clients see the changes the following day. The issue they are having is that my username is remembered after I log off, so they need to type in theirs' username to login. Is there an option to set a default username for a pc, so when I log off clients won't need to type in a user name (the default one will be already set)?

Comment: Hi, I think there's no way to revert back their username when someone logs-in to their pc. By the way, are you sure that you are logging-off and not pressing "Switch user". Typically, when you log-off, it will remove even your credentials on the log-on screen of the PC.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure there is a way to set a default username, you can change the last logged in user by altering the following registry key:

*HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\LastLoggedOnUser*

For a domain account, make sure to put it in this format: DOMAIN\username

Reboot the PC and the account you specify should show up as the last logged in user.